# Fixed background within an Absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to achieve two fixed banners on either side of my sites wrapper. I have used absolute positioning to attach the banner divs to each side of the wrapper and have set a fixed background within each so the banner follows the users down the page.

I seem to be having issues setting the background position of the banners, the background position does not seem to be relative to the parent div. I would like the banner backgrounds to be centered within the divs.

Code and example [site](http://www.makebelievemedia.co.uk/testing/test/)

```
<style>
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 970px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#F00;
}

#left-bg {
    width: 306px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -306px;
    background:url(http://www.superfreeslotgames.com/basecamp/L-Leovegas-banner.gif);
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#right-bg {
    width: 306px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -306px;
    background:url(http://www.superfreeslotgames.com/basecamp/R-Leovegas-banner.gif);
    background-position: top center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center right;
}
</style>

<div class="page-container">  
  <div id="left-bg"></div>
  <div id="right-bg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“the background position does not seem to be relative to the parent div”_ – of course it isn’t, because you are using `background-attachment:fixed`, which makes the viewport the reference point.

Comment: I though the fixed attachment was relative? Is there another option to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

change your CSS like this:

```
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 970px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color:#F00;

    }

#left-bg {
    width: 306px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -306px;
    background:url(http://www.superfreeslotgames.com/basecamp/L-Leovegas-banner.gif) no-repeat 100% 0;
}

#right-bg {
    width: 306px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -305px;
    background:url(http://www.superfreeslotgames.com/basecamp/R-Leovegas-banner.gif) no-repeat 100% 0;
}
```

Also, unless you're doing it by design, you should consider changing `right: -305px;` (which I also changed from your column because it adds a 1px blank space to the left of the column) to `right:0`